# Dart compiler gets generic as object

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, compiler-errors, functional-programming

I am building a dart/flutter app at the moment and I am trying with generics. There is an Api-Call which returns the class Result containing an error or the fetched json. I created a function in the result class, which handles errors and an actual result. An option is to specify a Function to parse the json (Otherwise specify an empty result as function). This function returns the type parameter T. This parse function is called if no error is present, a valid parse function specified and an result present is and passes it to the onSuccess function.

Now the problem:
The dart/flutter compiler doesn't recognize the type parameter anymore but as an Object... And I don't know why...

Here the necessary code:

handle function:

```
  static final expectEmpty = Result.empty();

  Widget handle<T>(
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) parse,
      Widget? Function(ApiError)? onError,
      Widget Function(T) onSuccess
      ) {
    Widget? ret;
    if (errorPresent()) {//If error occurred
      if (onError != null) ret = onError(error!);//Error which could be thrown
      return ret ?? handleCommonError();//If error wasn't handled
    } else {
      if (resultPresent() && T is! Result) {//If result present and valid parse function specified
        return onSuccess(parse(result!));//Return Widget function onSuccess with parsed result
      } else if (T is Result) {//Otherwise if empty result is expected
        return onSuccess(expectEmpty as T);//Return onSuccess without parse
      } else {//If nothing handled, try common errors
        return handleCommonError();
      }
    }
  }
```

Call of handle function:

```
     if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data!.handle((json) => Articles.fromJson(json).articles,
                  (error) {
                    //TODO: implement errors
                  },
                  (articles) {
                    return ListView.separated(
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final article = articles![index];
                          return _newsCard(article);
                        },
                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return const Divider(height: 0);
                        },
                        itemCount: articles!.length);
                  });
        }
```

Compiler output:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my Problem:
If `handle(...` is called the compiler has no clue because there is not generic type on the function call specified. To avoid that it must be specified in the call of the function:
`handle<Articles>(...`

Sources:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89745

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42766

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.